# Holoviews colors and colorbar based on datetimes

Tags: python, time-series, bokeh, scatter-plot, holoviews

I am new to holoviews and bokeh and I am trying to create a scatter plot from a time series where the colors are based on the dates. Something similar to the third code cell on this page: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/GLM-rolling-regression.html

Does anyone know how to do it?

Ps: I need to use holoviews with a bokeh backend.

Example:
[image: holoviews colorbar based on datetime]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm solving this by **overwriting the tick labels of a colorbar with the dates** by using parameter:

```
 colorbar_opts={
     'major_label_overrides'={}
 }
```

**Here's a working example (simplified):**

```py
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

# create sample data
X = np.random.normal(size=(2, 1000))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'col1': X[0],
        'col2': X[1],
        # use 'date' to overwirte the ticklabels of the colorbar
        'date': pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', freq='D', periods=1000),
    }
)

# use 'time_color' for the colorbar, since the colors need to be a float or int
df['time_color'] = df.index.to_series()


# draw scatter plot
# using the 'time_color' column to color the markers
# and overwrite the tick label using the date column

cbar_opts = dict(
                major_label_overrides  = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_dict(),
                major_label_text_align = 'left',
                )

hv_coloured = df.hvplot.points(x='col1', y='col2', c='time_color'
                              ).opts(colorbar_opts=cbar_opts, cmap='viridis')

hv_coloured
```

[image: hv_coloured example]

If you do `hv.help(hv.Points)` you can get more explanation on all available options around colorbar:

> colorbar:
> Whether to display a colorbar.

> colorbar_opts:
> Allows setting specific styling options for the colorbar overriding
> the options defined in the colorbar_specs class attribute. Includes
> location, orientation, height, width, scale_alpha, title, title_props,
> margin, padding, background_fill_color and more.

> colorbar_position:
> Allows selecting between a number of predefined
> colorbar position options. The predefined options may be customized in the
> colorbar_specs class attribute.

This question pointed me in the right direction:

[How do I manually set the tick locations of a colorbar for a Points plot in HoloViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687743/how-do-i-manually-set-the-tick-locations-of-a-colorbar-for-a-points-plot-in-holo)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really solved my problem.

Comment: @[Sander van den Oord](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3489155/sander-van-den-oord) Many thanks for the helpful answer! Proposed some code revisions.  Please feel free to undo my in case these aren't helpful.